# Cross reference collections in Expression<Func<>>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following expression that I am using in a linq to entities query

```
private Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>> ViewerProfileCheckExp(IViewerProfileModel vpSource)
    {
        return (pe) => pe.ViewerProfiles.Any(vp => vp.ViewLevel.Id == vpSource.ViewLevelId &&
                                                        vp.ViewTransitId == vpSource.ViewTransitId &&
                                                        vp.ViewGroups.ContainsAny(vpSource.Groups));
    }
```

In the last clause I would like to be able to return true in the condition if any of the ViewGroups in vp are contained in vpSource.Groups.  I realize that ContainsAny does not exist but I am wondering how to integrate what I want into the expression.

Answer (score 1):

What you're logically looking for is whether or not the intersection of the two collections has any items:

```
vp.ViewGroups.Intersect(vpSource.Groups).Any()
```